# codeigniter .htaccess won't work after I uploaded my files to the server

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. And It really get me frustrated. I tried to remove this index.php stuff. When I run my code in local server (localhost) it run well. It loads all my CSS and JS.  Now the application is online at [http://www.socialfansmafia.com][1]

[1]: http://www.socialfansmafia.com . you can check it out. It would ask you to log in with your twitter. Don't worry it's not a scam. I am using elliot houghin twitter library.

And none of my css and JS loaded. Please help me guys. I got a presentation in the next 4 hours :-(

This is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have set the `$config['index_page'] = '';` in the config files, and all of this code is run success in localhost.. but it won't work at the Online server... any advice guys? Best Regard - alfin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L,PT]
```

Comment: I found this rules more flexible since will make Apache check the requested file to see if it's not a regular file or directory. If it doesn't, it will append the requested path to the index.php turning it into a CodeIgniter URI.

You won't need to change your .htaccess if your publicly-accessible directory structure changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll safe your advice for my further development. But, for now I think `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js)` is quite nice for me. Thank you :-)

Comment: I change my mind. I got mp3 files to work with and your solution is more competible for me :-) ... thank you!!

Comment: Nice solution, but be careful of what files and directories are actually in (or under) your docroot with this .htaccess file. If you have hidden directories (.svn or .git) or other files that have sensitive information - then they will be accessible.

Comment: It's a bad practice to allow public raw access to SVN or GIT repositories, so I don't think that would be a very likely scenario. What one should do is to use svn export or git archive to get a clean copy of the repository without the private .svn or .git subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your .htaccess to allow the css and js folders:

```
# just add css|js to the RewriteCond

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js) #update this line
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

this tells apache to allow web access to files within the `css` and `js` folders. Otherwise, it routes those requests to the index.php file (which just issues a 404).